# Does extending GPL code make the new code GPL too?

Tags: open-source, licensing, gpl

I am currently adding some functionality to a popular open source project. It written in C and in Every file GPL license text is embedded. The functionality I am adding is not supported by the project. So you can say its some sort of extending.

My code gets compiled when the main project is compiled. My code is inside the main project and its integrated heavily.

Let me explain more thoroughly. Basically I know of two types of linking.

1. My *program* uses mysql c api. so I link my c code with `libmysqlclient`. Here I am **using** `libmysqlclient`
2. My *code*  adds hash-table functionality on `libmysqlclient` so user can access fields by column name.

My project is of second type. Should it be GPL?  What about the first scenario (I am curious)?

Comment: My understanding is that the type of linking matters. Are you statically or dynamically linking to the GPL'd project?

Comment: For case 1, its dynamic linking for sure.  And for my project (case 2) I dont know. I compile the main project and my source gets compiled. May be its static linking.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: For LGPL, yes; the rules on dynamic linking are more relaxed. For GPL, no; linking is linking.

Comment: @MasonWheeler [Debatable, according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Point_of_view:_static_linking_violates_GPL_but_unclear_as_of_dynamic_linking). I tried to parse some of the references, but I'm no where near familiar enough with the nuances of the law to do so. Although I would suspect someone who is more familiar with GNU and using the GLP would be.

Comment: The GPL only applies of you re-distribute it. If it is for personal use then no problems.

Comment: @LokiAstari its not for personal use, rather it'll be sold commercially. But this is a very small part of the whole project and we are happy to open source it. But we want to be sure about it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The GPL is a viral license; anything you extend the project with, or even link to it with shared libraries, must either be GPL or a compatible license, which includes many but not all other open-source licenses.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to create a derived work. To do that you need permission of the copyright holder. If the work you want to modify is GPL licensed, then the license gives you this permission. You can use the derived work privately or within your company without any obligation.

If you want to distribute the derived work (or just the original) you need the permission of the copyright holder. The GPL license gives you permission to distribute the work but only if you distribute it under the GPL license. (And promise to provide the complete source code).

Nothing makes your code GPL licensed. But there are situation where you have the choice between GPL - licensing your code or committing copyright infringement.

Answer (score 1):

In case (2), where you have actually added code to an existing GPL'ed project, the GPL is very clear that you are creating a derived work, which is subject to the GPL.

In the case of (1), there is some disagreement about whether or not linking to a GPL library obligates you to license your product under the GPL.  Personally, I am of the mind that you can do whatever you want by linking to a GPL library.  It seems to me that in this case, you are simply making use of the library, not creating a derived work.

However, it is also good to know that there is another license called the "LGPL" which specifically states that you are not obligated to license a product under the GPL as a result of linking to an LGLP library.

Comment: I also think case 1 is just **using** the library. It should not be GPL. The main project is 100% GPL. So I can not think about LGPL.

Comment: You're going to have to read the license yourself and use your best judgement in case 1.  In case 2 though, I think it's very clear that you are creating a derived work.

Comment: The FSF [takes a specific position on this](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL).  In short, if you link to GPL'd code, your code has to be GPL-compatible, and the whole combination is automagically GPL'd.  That strikes me as a little weird, but since they hold the copyright to (e.g.) GNU Readline, it's probably a good idea to at least be aware of this interpretation.

Comment: It’s actually plain copyright law that says adding things to any code, however licensed, is creating a derived work, and you need permission by the copyright holder. GPL gives you the permission to do it (under some conditions). Other licenses might or might not.